# Java Generated XML file is having different header information

Tags: java

I have written a Java class which generate and place the XML file I a particular location.
This the Java class is loaded into Oracle using the loadjava command. When I call the SQL Java procedure Java class  then will be called and the XML file is generating.

But my problem is with XML header i.e in the header it is getting as

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
```

Where as I am generating the XML file from by just Java call instead from Oracle the header is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

I am thinking that this could be reason with different jar using Oracle side.

Could you please let us know the reason for this.

Comment: According to XML spec, those are functionally identical, and are syntactically correct. Where is the problem?

Comment: What is the **problem** you are facing? Both are understood well by xml parsers

Comment: Thank you very much responce. But what could be difference  setting for the two generation.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle bundles its own implementation of Java's standard SAX, DOM and XSLT Api. More information can be found on the [Oracle XML Developer Kit page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/xmldevkit/index.html). This implementation might use a slightly different serialization than the one bundled with the JDK, but the differences shouldn't matter to a XML parser.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is the other system at client will take the xml file as input and that system is checking the header string should be  as <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ? Due to this I have manipulated the generated xml file with <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>  and changed to <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?> by checking char length.

Comment: Conti..It was worked at Client environment till with Oracle 10.2.0.1.0 and when client migrated the database from 10.2.0.1.0 to 10.2.3.0 from this the new header is coming differently. Due to this my logic fails. Please help me to change the settings to work as to Oracle 10.2.0.1.0

Comment: If the receiving system can't handle additional whitespace and different quotes in the xml prolog then it is not using an xml parser and should be fixed, sorry.